# Design Pattern for Pipleline/Stages in application

Tags: php, algorithm, oop, laravel, design-patterns

In my application, there are some stages through which a lead has to go through.

For example:

```
New
In Progress
Won
Lost
```

These are just four stages of 11 stages. On every stage, there will be some action that has to be performed.

For example, a lead moves from New to In Progress, I need to update a certain set of values in four tables.

What could be the ideal design pattern that I could use here so that in future if any new stage comes in, it becomes easy to accommodate that in code?

I was thinking of using Factory Pattern.

EDIT:
I did something like this:

```
interface StageInterface
{
    public function changeStage($previous_stage, $next_stage, $ticket_details);
}

abstract class ParentStage implements StageInterface
{
    public function changeStage($previous_stage, $next_stage, $ticket_details)
    {
        $ticket_details->stage_id = $next_stage;
        $ticket_details->save();

        return $this;
    }
}

Class InProgress extends ParentStage
{
}

class TicketStagesFactory
{
    protected $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getObject()
    {
        switch ($this->data) {

            case Stage::IN_PROGRESS:
                return new \App\Http\Controllers\Stages\InProgress();
                break;
     }
}
```

And then I am using the factory like this:

```
$factory = new TicketStagesFactory($next_stage);
$test = $factory->getObject()->changeStage($previous_stage, $next_stage, $ticket_details);
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This actually looks more like a workflow.
State machine works more like this:
 for a state, a event will cause it to transition to another state.
A workflow works more like what you've said:
 For a state, actions have to be performed, the outcome of these actions decide the next state.

I would look for a workflow engine for php to make your work maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you program flow, but and idea could be:

```
//ABSTRACT CLASS FOR A STAGE
abstract class LeadStage
{
    protected $lead;

    //INJECT YOUR LEAD OBJECT
    public function __construct( Lead $lead )
    {
        $this->lead = $lead;
    }

    //handle the stage logic on the $lead object
    public abstract function handle();
}

//CONCRETE CLASS FOR A STAGE
class InProgress extends LeadStage
{
    //HANDLE THE CONCRETE STAGE LOGIC ON THE LEAD OBJECT
    public function handle()
    {
        //do some logic on $this->lead;
    }
}

//LEAD OBJECT
class Lead
{
    protected $leadStage;

    public function construct(  )
    {
        //here build your first LeadStage object: you could also use a factory
        //pattern to create the LeadStage instance
        $this->leadStage = //...
    }

    public function setStage( LeadStage $stage )
    {
        $this->leadStage = $stage;    
    }

    public function handleStage()
    {
        $this->leadStage->handle();
    }
}
```

And use the classes like this:

```
$lead = new Lead();

//will handle the first stage
$lead->handle();

//something causes the stage to change
$lead->setStage( new InProgress( $lead ) );

//will handle the InProgess stage logic
$lead->handleStage();
```

So, using a single class for every stage, will delegate the responability to handle the stage logic to the object of the specific class.

When you need to add a status you only have to create e new `LeadStage` implementation

Comment: I've added my implementation, can you please see if its correct?

Comment: @phantomphoenix : the signature of `changeStage` method is different from your interface and iplementations. It sohuld be the same. Consider to pass a `ticket` object to the stages objects as a dependency, as i've shown in my example

Comment: Ohh. Yes, I was changing that. Might have missed out. But is the implementation correct, in general senses?

Comment: @phantomphoenix : usually you can't say if a Pattern is 'correct' or not, it depends on the context and on how it's used; if you feel it's appropriate for your architecture, then go for it